# VBA: Application-Defined Error when running LastRow Code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the last row of data after opening an excel Workbook but it's returning "Run Time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" I've used this format for code many times so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
I defined the variable as Long, does anyone have any ideas?  My code is below:

```
Function get_end_row(ByVal column_with_data As Long) As Long
Dim last_row As Long

last_row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows.Count
get_end_row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(last_row, column_with_data).End(xlUp).Row

End Function

Sub Master()
Call MVP
End Sub

Sub MVP()
Dim endRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow1 As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
endRow = get_end_row(1)

Set mvpcomm = Workbooks.Open("File Path")
Set wsMVPComm = mvpcomm.Sheets("Combined")
lastRow1 = wsMVPComm.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
wsMVPComm.Range("A2:AZ" & lastRow1).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & endRow + 1)



End Sub
```

If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it!  Thank you.

Comment: What row does the debugger stop on (highlight) after the error pops up? In general, I've seen this error when VBA has trouble finding a particular range, either because a different workbook happens to be active, or a sheet name has changed.

Comment: The code stops on lastRow1 = wsMVPComm.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: step through your code and see which line actually throws the error

Comment: @Mr.Burns the line of code that returns the error doesn't utilize that part of the code

Comment: Try this: `wsMVPComm.Range("A" & wsMVPComm.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I suspect your workbooks are different formats. Use: `lastRow1 = wsMVPComm.Range("A" & wsMVPComm.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Excellent!! wsMVPComm.Range("A" & wsMVPComm.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row did the trick, I guess it got confused on which workbook it was counting rows for?  Thank you all so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most probably the workbook you opened as `wsMVPComm` is of an old excel format while `ThisWorkbook` is of a new one

try

```
lastRow1 = wsMVPComm.Range("A" & wsMVPComm.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

instead of

```
lastRow1 = wsMVPComm.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

you could make your function a little more generic and help you avoiding such problems like follows

```
Function get_ws_end_row(ws As Worksheet, column_with_data As Long) As Long
    get_end_row = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, column_with_data).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

and then you could use it twice in the code you posted

```
endRow = get_ws_end_row(ws, 1)
...
lastRow1 = get_ws_end_row(wsMVPComm, 1)
```